# Please solve this error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

react-refresh-runtime.development.js:315 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

```
const Exchange = () => {
  const { exchanges, setExchanges } = useState([]);
  const { loading, setLoading } = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchExchanges = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`${server}/exchanges`);
      // console.log(data);
      setExchanges(data);
      setLoading(false);
    };
    fetchExchanges();
  });
  return (
    <Container maxW={"container.xl"}>{loading ? ( <Loader /> ): (<>
        <HStack>
            {exchanges.map((i) => 
             (
                    <div>{i.name}</div>
                ))}
        </HStack>
    </>)}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Comment: `setExchanges(data);` is probably causing the issue. Please `console.log` your data making sure that it is an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
const { exchanges, setExchanges } = useState([]);
  const { loading, setLoading } = useState(true);
```

this

```
  const [ exchanges, setExchanges ] = useState([]);
  const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to render exchanges that you fetch asynchronously. Therefore, it is empty when the code starts to execute `exchanges.map`block. You can't map an empty array and get i.name out. Try waiting it to be filled with axios call by adding optional chaining.

```
exchanges?.map((i) =>  .........
```

Comment: or you can also do something like `exchanges.length > 0 && exchanges.map()`

Comment: This is wrong. You absolutely can call .map() on an empty array, which is why it's good to initialize state to [] instead of null/undefined (assuming it's an array). Also, because it's empty, .map() will never iterate and thus i.name will never get called. So that couldn't possibly be the issue either. The issue is the state is getting set to undefined from a bad GET response, so the unproblematic initial [] state is getting overwritten by undefined. The solution here would be to debug & add error checking on the GET response.